# Anchor templates in GitLab-CI YAML file: how to reuse with different appended attributes

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

If an anchor is used like the [example](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#anchors) to define re-usable parts, but I would like to define the `expire_in` attribute of the `artifacts` keyword differently for each re-use of the template, the [CI Linter](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/lint.html) reports:

> Error: (): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at ... (Line on which *save_ipk is used)

```
.templ: &save_ipk
  stage: build
  script:
    - ls package/*.ipk
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - package/*.ipk
#...

save_ipk_tags:
  <<: *save_ipk
    expire_in: 6 months
  only:
    - tags

save_ipk_mr:
  <<: *save_ipk
    expire_in: 1 month
  only:
   - merge_requests
```

I would have expected that the content of template `save_ipk` gets merged and then the `expire_in` attribute is fine under `artifacts` (Like a C pre-processor substitution). My only solution was to take out the whole artifacts section of the template and repeat it.

Comment: Is this your actual file? It is invalid YAML, as you cannot indent the key `expire_in` more than the key `<<`, and you also cannot use an alias `*save_ipk` without having `&save_ipk`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. (The original file had the right alias) I did not find any explanation, in which the order of the anchor-substituation and verification is done, do you have any sources? I suppose on the long run I will have to have a look at GitLab's [include](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#include)